# didReceiveRemoteNotification is not receiving notifications through FCM

Tags: ios, swift3, firebase-cloud-messaging, unusernotificationcenter, remote-notifications

I've implemented Firebase Cloud Messaging as per instructions given on their website. So when I generate notification from here:
[image]

And in `AppDelegate.swift` I've added `didReceiveRemoteNotification` function as:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],

     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
```

Other methods I've implemented are 

`func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String)`

`func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage)`
`func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)`

Whereas my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` has:

```
 if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM
            Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        FirebaseApp.configure()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.InstanceIDTokenRefresh, object: nil)

        return true
```

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look this gist file 
[AppDelegate file for FCM](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5082cc5878c4857a02ca6300251f690d)

In XCode Goto Targets > Capabilities & make sure your Push Notifications is on.
[image]
Hope it helps.